# Simulating field inheritence with composition

Tags: inheritance, struct, enums, rust, composition

I have several pairs of structs for which the fields of one is a perfect superset of the other.  I'd like to simulate some kind of inheritance so I don't have to have separate cases for each struct since that would almost double my code.

In a language like C, I could simulate inheritance of fields with something like this:

```c
struct A
{
    int a;
};

struct B
{
    struct A parent;
    int b;
};

main()
{
    struct B test1;
    struct A *test2 = &test1;
    test2->a = 7;
}
```

I want to do something like this in Rust.  I read about something like that [here](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/08/20/virtual-structs-part-3-bringing-enums-and-structs-together/#common-fields) but when I tried it, it doesn't seem to have been implemented yet.  Is there any way to do reuse the fields in a struct inside another without separate case handling?

Here is the enum syntax I tried:

```
enum Top
{
    a: i32,
    A {},
    B {
        b: i32
    }
}
```

And this is my error:

```
error: expected one of `(`, `,`, `=`, `{`, or `}`, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:3:6
  |
3 |     a: i32,
  |      ^ expected one of `(`, `,`, `=`, `{`, or `}` here
```

[Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=27ef5c590501a0b92168b8324c5017ec&version=nightly) to some sample execution.

Comment: "*when I tried it, it doesn't seem to have been implemented yet*" care to share what you tried? The errors you ran into? Put it on https://play.rust-lang.org/ so others can run it too.

Answer (score 3):

The proposed syntax for common fields in enums hasn't been implemented as of Rust 1.22. The only option right now is plain old composition. If you want to be able to operate generically on multiple types that contain an `A`, you may be able to define a trait that provides access to that `A` and implement it on all of those types:

```
trait HaveA {
    fn a(&self) -> &A;
    fn a_mut(&mut self) -> &mut A;
}

impl HaveA for B {
    fn a(&self) -> &A {
        &self.parent
    }

    fn a_mut(&mut self) -> &mut A {
        &mut self.parent
    }
}
```

Comment: I up voted it because it would work around the problem, but I'm holding out choosing it for the solution because it seems like there should be a better way.  I guess I was expecting tighter control out of a systems programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively emulate inheritance using composition, and to make it transparent (with no overhead), simply use [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html).

```
struct A {
    number: usize,
}

struct B {
    a: A
}

impl std::ops::Deref for B {
    type Target = A;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.a
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = B {
        a: A {
            number: 42
        }
    };

    println!("{}", b.number);
}
```

You will also need `DerefMut` if you plan on having a `mut B` and modify A's field through it.